# Directed and Undirected Hyperedge

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to define an API for manipulating graphs and hypergraphs. Does it make sense to talk about directed and undirected hyperedges in an hypergraph? Can we talk about successors and predecessors nodes in the case of undirected hyperedges (or edges) ?

Answer (score 2):

You have lots of choice. One approach would be to associate a total order with each edge in the hypergraph. But you also have the option of using just a partial order. Or you could view the edge as the vertex set of a complete graph, and then orient each edge. (So each edge would be a tournament.)

Which choice was best would depend on the immediate needs of the problem.